# in_place_constructor helper type

Tags: template, c++20, constructor

recently I implemented a little helper class, which can be primarily utilized on perfect forwarding constructors.

### Introduction

As a slight example, let me pull in two of the `std::pair` constructors:

```cpp
template< class U1, class U2 >
constexpr pair( U1&& x, U2&& y );  // (1)

template< class... Args1, class... Args2 >
constexpr pair( std::piecewise_construct_t,
                std::tuple<Args1...> first_args,
                std::tuple<Args2...> second_args );  // (2)
```

see: [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair)

You have the choice to either construct your first/second manually in forehand, or you have to provide the `std::piecewise_construct` tag object and must wrap the arguments in a tuple.

Given the `immobile` neither copy- nor movable type:

```cpp
template <class... Ts>
class immobile
{
public:
    ~immobile() = default;

    immobile(const immobile&) = delete;
    immobile& operator =(const immobile&) = delete;
    immobile(immobile&&) = delete;
    immobile& operator =(immobile&&) = delete;

    template <class... Args>
        requires std::constructible_from<std::tuple<Ts...>, Args...>
    explicit immobile(Args&&... args)
        : value{std::forward<Args>(args)...}
    {
    }

    std::tuple<Ts...> value;
};
```

We can not use the `(1)` of the pair constructor - we have to use the second one:

```cpp
std::pair<immobile<std::string, int>, int> p1(immobile<std::string, int>{"Hello, World!", 1337}, 42); // error
std::pair<immobile<std::string, int>, int> p2{std::piecewise_construct, std::tuple{"Hello, World!", 1337}, std::tuple{42}};
```

This is noisy and we have to explicitly wrap our arguments as tuples and most importantly: There is absolutely no benefit for the `int` member to provide the argument as a tuple.

### Solution

I would like to have the choice to individually provide the arguments of the pair elements and get rid of that `std::piecewise_construct`.

I came up with that little helper class:

```cpp
namespace sl
{
    template <class Type, class... Args>
        requires std::same_as<Type, std::remove_cvref_t<Type>>
            && std::constructible_from<Type, Args...>
    struct in_place_constructor
    {
    public:
        in_place_constructor(const in_place_constructor&) = delete;
        in_place_constructor& operator =(const in_place_constructor&) = delete;
        in_place_constructor(in_place_constructor&&) = delete;
        in_place_constructor& operator =(in_place_constructor&&) = delete;

        ~in_place_constructor() = default;

        [[nodiscard]]
        in_place_constructor() = default;

        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr operator Type() && noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<Type, Args...>)
        {
            return std::make_from_tuple<Type>(std::move(m_Args));
        }

        template <class T, class... Ts>
        friend constexpr auto in_place(Ts&&... args) noexcept;

    private:
        std::tuple<Args...> m_Args;

        [[nodiscard]]
        explicit constexpr in_place_constructor(std::tuple<Args...>&& args) noexcept
            : m_Args{std::move(args)}
        {
        }
    };

    template <class Type, class... Args>
    [[nodiscard]]
    constexpr auto in_place(Args&&... args) noexcept
    {
        return in_place_constructor<Type, Args&&...>{std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)};
    }
}
```

which let me rewrite the initialization from above as:

```cpp
std::pair<immobile<std::string, int>, int> p3{sl::in_place<immobile<std::string, int>>("Hello, World!", 1337), 42};
```

But wait, there is more!

#### Explicitly expecting `in_place_constructor` as ctor argument

Custom classes can utilize that helper type for themselves and expecting that as one or multiple constructor arguments. For example:

```cpp
template <class T1, class T2, class T3>
class MultiInPlaceExpecting
{
public:
    template <class... T1s, class... T2s, class... T3s>
    explicit MultiInPlaceExpecting(
        sl::in_place_constructor<T1, T1s...>&& args1,
        sl::in_place_constructor<T2, T2s...>&& args2,
        sl::in_place_constructor<T3, T3s...>&& args3)
        : value1{std::move(args1)},
        value2{std::move(args2)},
        value3{std::move(args3)}
    {
    }

    T1 value1;
    T2 value2;
    T3 value3;
};

const MultiInPlaceExpecting<std::optional<int>, std::string, int> obj{
    sl::in_place<std::optional<int>>(1337),
    {}, // default ctor
    {}  // default ctor
};

// CTAD!
const MultiInPlaceExpecting obj{
    sl::in_place<std::optional<int>>(1337),
    sl::in_place<std::string>("Hello, World!"),
    sl::in_place<int>(42)};
```

### Questions

Even if I'm quite hyped about my solution, I'm a bit afraid, that I missed something important. I explicitly deleted the copy and move ctors/assignments, enable the converting operator only for rvalue-refs and generally do not see much room, where it could go heavily wrong.

The second question is: Is that the best I can do? Or is there anything I can improve?

If you want to play around, I setup a godbolt project including some test cases: [https://godbolt.org/](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMwAbKSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEegAOqAqETgwe3r4BwSlpjgLhkTEs8Ylctpj2hQxCBEzEBFk%2BfkFVNRn1jQTF0XEJegoNTS057cM9faXlEgCUtqhexMjsHOb%2BEcjeWADUJv5uogTICGYA9MenAPpKCmkCAHQISUkH2CYaAIIbWzuY%2B0OVzOlyYJwQ1wImGG1xYTGQxFSz1e70%2BP2%2BvwY2y8ewObgIXiS9FRGLMmyx/0BHiStTEJJ%2BZL%2BOIBeOGxAiwHpaLRzDYCiS8IBClo3IA7FZvrspbsoSwiWCWUCDPddgAVACeSUwpF22yY90eht2X2IwAUXI0AE5iJgAI5ePA2hS7YboEAgBSsTDXfV4jVanWu902lioABu3uQYZtVEhfs1mFR/g%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%2BeOpzUY0rTPL0oy/KcwLgqY27UHu1YID5pnAle0WFA%2B1B4swGkyP5yq6uWRrybYiyip1e3OMdw1UXFZL%2BGILKvJ9BRuohqn3RjuPjcOHXBuduYGwqxaFZlsUcZ5L1%2BUFfYMSlz5LWVhVNuVGG1SOlN0UtdW8BYUNYjoRNHMtb3%2B7HCcp0UgerRErvUB7%2Bhop4wjbLkhWx5rzvu97v9gLbKeZ8TLjrL4kjfvHy01%2Bn3v30/Rjf3Xbf1%2BJfeoMIy8j5Xq0z93jCd4vh3JOf4jl5WlXt/B%2BtEwrXygl/e%2Be8w5/xgvxRSbca511VkqfUTcs5vxPjae0jpoRNXdBTYspZ2qVlZMNEANNIaHQZtgEO9MI66yQVafGhMNwfw3qHTMTt3pYJrtzQG3hExRwoWnLyeIs4i3emVAu/ca6D2YQPWRit5FWjBj1ahMN3i7EEV4V%2BciC6zTHigxURxG5qgtO3cxAAxEg6d8BGDcKqN8Bjj7DwJqPORVoTFUmSj2CMTR8reiIH6bRk1LE11YcgImtjY5eQ5E41c4SHYswql4k%2BAixB6P5tHOx4jM6mneFI4A%2BcS5AKAdXcpSiymKNVDorJ%2BikGGN%2Bm3HxatzGqkserAAkgwZQyFsDBUwMWIwK9KmWncZOYGii2loINEaTB6SolE16f0wUgytQjOAElWg7oA6oXYn6ehpVGEfBSTnPhVpMlCJyRQoWxSXby3SQo1R1TEGvLqboxp8jmnvO8ZgOUKtTHq1VJUXUHSzC7Q6f4Lp5iACydk8CrIGUMrZYy3Hjg8dM15syzHoNeqChQUL8UHTMES8FJLHhqn8C3LByyNwIrkkivpKLNmOCMBAS5lphR7PnIBIhh4%2BpgsJbQ56tFnaVC5TylKfKsICrfH1SFaoyWivOXWSFUrdkyq3KxA5Qc%2Br%2BB1KqGlqqw4swUP4NJij%2BH1KEVwW5zVwzCwlaU0gXKvlmAdSNJ1DyzCuvdQ0mFIjHVjWdpap51rxk/JqR8rgtq9H2qMVU1UZh42YE9Umk%2Bxq00wszfLIxyi0SqmwEIVU1woZCEGuYMw%2BycK6kMLseIuwvCOAJgAL0wOgXYHUWAygTOSrKCBJwIF2FdYZBBnRE31G2CduoIqix8IwAgjYzBKurS5FtdBCDqiMquq1LyrSVqcd0gA8lETlq6hCEhSE0Z0/jGBnUEAvGScliZ9gyNW/dFTj411vsi9ZqL2WckOMlD8tIRSHAiPZD4cNp7aG9sOAuvzlqvIAErYAAIpyG6ehlOIAGCyVoGB08T84OPC%2BTNH9hb%2B5HtVKe891ar2vBILOpxXxDJ7vRVg2j9GL1mAAOoIEYPDJ1b7zJAZXX6vhUaqnJTZByHMA5hyroABLVCIzqfjJBaDoDAGAddyHrVWj/SygDbKFNwZyVq0S5C8zydGcmPD9y2TTXzS015Nd0NYZw1W1T6nUCae07p/Tq6SPzzIxRwBJ8I3cewMes9fHBPCbQEkdUYm8pGEk1%2B6LMmT63zk3uBTbJvZ%2BdoBp3YWniA6b0wZwyeaqkmbWasDZ46LOxHg1HazsrBS2fdPZ4Dg0XNub%2BdFq0XnsO4erWpsrAWKtBZq6FqCpH2vkYaZR6TMaqk8YS9WpLjUF1sCfQKjkWXpM/oa/%2Bf9zXANtY6wLLrOrIYFfZA53zZhpvlcq9VkLUnDNcvGz5vjH3ZtfeC9WsLZ4Itrai9GkbNdtsMdXdgCMjVB3JcDkBu%2B596B9q1PWT9Z2uWNdZa1owdF2tWd5Y9vEHDabPY5DqKDSY3vA8C1VsHq6dSSF%2B3V9zVTPOYYm4NihVCSvvf82z771aueesWhD8n2hVtCKV3o9bzzqNvKrjU4tpby1fErXx2t4mfyiEak2zd7bO10UasgLw76BA6jR41O3VuBC7E/FQcd3a8l6QUxZfa0v9iro3a27du6pNV2PgjvjTGb2zpsi%2Bjcx2BAE9cVg2%2BsT7EJOcQOEDFCwMZDpJBwQzOFeU%2B1Y%2BXrIAC8CCL24Jnx1HOlMAYogHuHkoEZmzSeXUOhFq6aZty00fdtCcakLdLB4Tup6aed7lFD%2BuKbF6zub7OFuy95%2Bn/8mf4mOJz1X/r2jLOdap5XvPdnCuvacz6lzzek2t8F4DqbEuV9S8WzxZbivIt5uo23Yfq69sXSpYT5bKnZp7pL5bz4X7ACL7Kbi4zaS4c7r4w7GZb4%2B4OLACJK55uD06vZl7H4V7IT75QFFJDZ/bpJt4s7P6g5r494rZf5UaD5/4Caj4syLpHYY5T6cZgGKIZ5oHZ4KrYGQEvYDZ4H3Yn6EFn59bEGOZP7wEv6IG3584nwUFA5UHzY/a0Gf7Q7f6MFxZ0Y7ZI4o67BO7AGY604AgED9qgEz6b5bzb6%2B674CHmFEHCGM4l6N7YCiHSo2aQYgJPZCEM5zjQZFKyGfbqGB7c6KFw5jYP7t4i4aJL5qGr4/Yy7iyaEq6YAZH96w5a6II65loVpvZG7URMSm6NoAgW54Adpdo9q47QiO5DqnCjqAbOgKCdQAioBUAyhCa9rTqEB3rzqmhsETqSY6jrpqSVGWHh77rjJMGx4sZ3oCAo6PobgJ52SmEfpcE2HgH/iMqOBXY4A3YOaCF5g17MAQb17uF0IEIehQFuHQaiEIYnhjGIbPFVRWBIYb4oZVIqEd6EbEZLbhZ0ENJcDZE/GxGDS956JmCPAAo0jqgSRgnKEQkQAaDpFfLho6EjZzHXoLG7BsYcYR7bE8G7GIoHEtZbKPHPJqIPan4nHuhnF14N4waDRcD%2BD%2BCigLCariE9aSG3HCEhGlZhHJGfpurUncq0kSGXHQYQCRHDbfHInea4ZskcnokglIkC5KmUFyHUEaGAmQ7AlCJSb1aWgqHc5qlCKYkMHFyIJQbwxMARAQBBEszIC7QICNAABULMhUakBkuwkEUsUo5w5wuw6oSwTESg4MuwZUyMzpTo6xT8bgYIpw7oQg0IDwDAEkjw%2B4mZLpOoosYY/pLeQZIZYZyw4KmAhgAAtISDGYrFKL7A1LsPGUvAWptorBwAsLshwCpLwH4BwFoKQKgJwG4NYNYC6OGasEHv4DwKQAQJoJ2QsC1CAIEDCZaKKIECpBoGyRoCpJIAABz%2BAaDSDdmSB9kLlDmcC8AKAgAaBzkLkLBwCwAwCID5hyi9xkAUB/jvn0CJDABcAaCQpYBhiTiYAABqZ0WUJ6Wo/Zs5NAckCQN5EAsQF5PczAxA6onAs5aFjQ6oJ67W46WFvAaAXcS6J6DAtAmFA5vAWAsQXgGBYgtAN53ANFAKhgwA4g1FpA%2BANoxYEYzFg5QUwyLaawg5UG1QF5BMsQX4GFHgWARFc57ILARFCwVABgZoEFmAUFMFCl/AggIgYg7AUgMgggigKg6gXFuglQBgRgKAY5lg%2BgJYN5sAvI7AwIkKASnAR5GgVZIUmAIFWl/gi5Q5NIGQzFVZroUEpglg1gZgg5TqxA7IWAzlEkHQrWzgEArgYwfglQYQEQ/QZQgwlQ%2BQ6QAg2VyQqQpVDA0wAwFQaVxYAg3QowngrQQwREDVdQIwvQ%2BVMwRVtgXV5VlQkwTQNVhVFQCwbRywqw8w%2BgnAvZpA/Z8VnAuwqg%2B5gQVZgQkguwwAyAyAuwAFjwqaEAuAhAP4GwoJvA851F00pAy5M5jwKk%2B54EKklolo25/gKk/gh5kKp5vAylW5C1F5w5HA15t59511pAT5r5SwBAY4BA5ALg%2BA/YeAbolQelwgog4g%2B5Jl8gSgagF5VlpAWUX4SQKls1PZ55XFwNJ6LacNdEXRq161m121u1%2B1Ggh1uwEAHgP5CQ05F14NWgN1QmTAWAiQqVv1pA/1d5i1vAwNoNd5V1gtS5AQoojwgF/gkgloa1lokgKkXAgQr15NQVgNVNV5AtwV3ZZglNS1IN5tN1ASGZIAkgQAA%3D%3D%3D)

Thanks for your time,

greetings Dominic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Making better use of existing functionality

You can in fact use the first form of `std::pair`'s constructor to create a pair where one or both members are immobile. You just have to pass it something that is not immobile that can be used to construct the immobile member(s), *and* specify `std::pair`'s template parameters explicitly:

```
std::pair<immobile<std::string, int>, int> p1{std::tuple<std::string, int>{"Hello, World!", 1337}, 42};
```

This is shorter than your declaration of `p3`.

Your objection against the second form of `std::pair`'s constructor is that it is too noisy. But you are merely replacing `std::piecewise_construct` with `sl::in_place</* repeated type name */>`, which I think is also noisy, and is not even that much shorter. Consider instead that you can create an abbreviation for `std::piecewise_construct`:

```
constexpr auto pwc = std::piecewise_construct;
…
std::pair<immobile<std::string, int>, int> p2{pwc, std::tuple{"Hello, World!", 1337}, std::tuple{42}};
```

That's just one byte longer than the non-compiling definition of `p1`!

## Avoid having to repeat type names

Your `class sl::in_place_constructor` needs to know `Type` at construction time. So `sl::in_place()` also needs to know `Type`. But this requires you to repeat the type name of the pair member. It would be nice if this could be avoided. Note that `Type` is only really necessary when calling the conversion operator. But when a conversion operator is called, the caller already knows what it wants to convert to... so could we let `Type` be deduced automatically? Let's make the conversion operator a template:

```
template <class... Args>
struct in_place_constructor
{
    …
    template<typename Type>
    [[nodiscard]]
    constexpr operator Type() && noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<Type, Args...>)
    {
        return std::make_from_tuple<Type>(std::move(m_Args));
    }

    template <class... Args>
    friend constexpr auto in_place(Args&&... args);

private:
    …
    [[nodiscard]]
    explicit constexpr in_place_constructor(std::tuple<Args...>&& args)
        : m_Args{std::move(args)}
    {
    }
};

template <class... Args>
[[nodiscard]]
constexpr auto in_place(Args&&... args)
{
    return in_place_constructor<Args&&...>{std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)};
}
```

Now you can write:

```
std::pair<immobile<std::string, int>, int> p3{sl::in_place("Hello, World!", 1337), 42};
```

## Incorrect use of `noexcept`

Be careful with `noexcept`: only use it when you are absolutely sure that nothing can throw. Moving arguments into a tuple? Depending on the types of the arguments, that can certainly happen. Either make `noexcept` conditional, or just remove it entirely: consider that none of `std::pair` and `std::tuple`'s constructors are `noexcept` either.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Looks very promising and I will have a deeper look tomorrow. But I'm wondering about the ``noexcept`` part. As ``std::forward_as_tuple`` is defined as ``noexcept`` and I'm simply making a tuple of references, that shouldn't ever throw. Even moving around a tuple of references shouldn't ever throw. Do I miss anything here?

Comment: Sure `std::forward_as_tuple()` itself might not throw, but you are still passing this to the constructor of `in_place_constructor`, which in turn uses it to construct `m_Args`, and *that* is not `noexcept`.

Comment: As the move constructor of ``std::tuple`` is defaulted, the ``noexcept`` specification is deduced by the compiler. And as I said, I`m moving a ``std::tuple`` out of pure references, which will never throw, but actually I do not mind making it conditional here, too.

Comment: That's a good point, but are you sure the move constructor will be invoked? You can still pass it a type that is copyable but not movable, in which case the copy constructor will be used despite the explicit `std::move()`.

Comment: Well, the copy-ctor is defaulted, too. So, the same applies here as well, because copying references will also never throw. But I see your point about the uncertainty and will simply make that conditionally ``noexcept``. Thanks!